# Creating a second User class(table) in Parse

Tags: parse-platform

Is it possible to create a second class in Parse that has the same attributes and characteristics as the User class and if so, how would one create the second class? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  Create it as you would any other class, and it will behave like any other -- which is to say **not** like the Parse supplied user, which provides login, signup, session, verification, inclusion in roles and ACLs, etc.

Comment: so I would have to create my own methods for sign in, sign up, etc?

Comment: Yes.   You'll also be on your own to do email validation.  If you do that, your users still cannot participate in security provided by ACLs or CLPs.   In short, it might be better to augment the real Parse.User by adding a pointer attribute to the class that you envision.